# Populating Drop-Down in PHP using Array

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a drop-down menu with values from an array.

I have tried to follow other answers but the syntax doesn't seem to be working. (I'm still relatively new to PHP).

The following code which I am working on was produced by someone else.

```
$sqlite_query = "SELECT * FROM dis_kind";
$result = $db->query($sqlite_query);
$array = $result->fetchArray();

$output = "<select name=\"kind\" class=\"dis\" >\n";
$output .= "<option value=\"$this->wildcard_value\"></option>\n";

foreach ($result as $array) {
    $value = $array['kind'];
    $output .= "<option value=\"";
    $output .= $value;
    $output .= "\">";
    $output .= $value;
    $output .= " - ";
    $output .= $array['description'];
    $output .= "</option>\n";
}

$output .= "</select>\n";
```

I don't know why it has been done the way it has but I am stumped as to getting my drop-down to work.

Currently, the box appears but is populated with no values.

Thanks.

Comment: You dont seem to be fetching any results from the resultset that we hope is created by your query

Comment: to render an "option", tru using "sprintf" function, makes things much easier ro read (try   sprintf("<option value=\"%s\">%s - %s</option>", $value, $value, $array['description']);)

Comment: try debugging...use `var_dump($result);` to see if it really has the expected data..or add the `query()` method too!!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually managed to solve the problem myself - before I pulled my hair out!

Instead of using the `foreach` loop, I used the following:

```
while($array = $result->fetchArray()) 
{
    // Output code.
}
```

Which populated the drop-down with values from the array.